# How to AppleScript the launching of sound.profPane?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have this script

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
    reveal anchor "Output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
```

The problem is that it first goes to the general configuration, with all those icons, only then, it focuses on sound. This create a quick and annoying flicker. I am only interested in the sound pane.

Is there nay way I can write a script that'll show JUST the sound pane without that flickering?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the reveal command directly:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
```

If you are using UI scripting, the activate command can also be left out:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        if selected of row 1 then
            set selected of row 2 to true
        else
            set selected of row 1 to true
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: the first script did not pass syntax check with the AppleScript editor